# ¿Es posible alterar una sección de un código HTML mediante la llamada de una función PHP?

Tags: php, html

Estoy creando una página web, y quiero saber si es posible que, al oprimir una sección de lista como esta:

```
            <li><a href = "Danza.html"><span class = ""><i class = ""></i></span>Danza</a>
              <ul>
                <li><a href = ""><span class = ""><i class = ""></i></span>Noticias</a></li>
                <li><a href = ""><span class = ""><i class = ""></i></span>Cartelera</a></li>
              </ul>
              <img src="Imágenes/Reflector.png" height="50" width="50"></img>
            </li>
```

Especificamente, usaría el "href" de los tags "li" para llamar la función de un php externo, y la sección que quiero que se cambie al llamar esa función es más adelante. ¿Es posible programar lo que acabo de decir? De antemano, gracias por su atención y tiempo.

Comment: Sí es posible, debes tener código Javascript para "escuchar" clic en los enlaces, realizar una petición asíncrona a PHP y esperar la respuesta para actualizar la sección que deseas, en conjunto se conoce como AJAX. Probablemente te sirva leer [esto](https://desarrolloweb.com/manuales/taller-ajax.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dependiendo de lo que quieras hacer, deberías empezar creando una función que escuche un click en los elementos que quieras.

Dentro de esa función, crearemos una llamada a esa función PHP que quieres, con AJAX, esta herramienta nos permite llevar a cabo acciones de manera asíncrona, sin recargar la página y seguir usando la página sin esperar.

```js
//Puedes usar 'li' o, si usarías una clase, '.class-name' o, usando un ID (solo para un elemento), sería '#id_element'
$('li').on('click', function() {
  //Algunas acciones a llevar a cabo inmediatamente después del click
  $.ajax({
      type: "POST", // O el tipo que estés usando en tu ruta
      url: '/routet',
      data: { // Si es POST, aquí defines los datos que mandarás en el $request
          'post_id': post_id
      },
      success: function success(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          //data trae lo que retorna la función a la que llamaste en la ruta
          //Lo que quieres que haga si fue exitoso el proceso
      },
      error: function error(data) {
          //console.log(data);
          //data trae el error que retorna la función a la que llamaste en la ruta
          //Lo que quieres que haga si fue falló el proceso
      }
  });
});
```

Puedes optar por añadir código en una etiqueta `script` en tu `head` pero yo recomendaría un archivo separado.

En tu caso, con Hostinger, dentro del panel de herramientas para desarrollador deberás encontrar una sección para editar el código de la página y agregar un archivo JS y en tu `head` añadir `<script src="js/myscript.js"></script>`

Comment: Cómo le hago para integrar Ajax a mi proyecto de mi página? Estoy usando como Host web Hostinger.